# Why do I get Repeat and "Untill" error when I convert a code From Pseudocode to program in Python?

Tags: python, pseudocode

I am converting pseudocode in the python program but I am stuck and giving me error for

> REPEAT

and

> UNTIL age >= min AND age <= max.

Please let me know how can I fix it. Thank you in advance

```
BEGIN
REPEAT
min = 18
max = 60
OUTPUT "what is your age?"
INPUT age
IF age < min or age > max THEN
 OUTPUT “Error - age must be between 18 and 60 "
ELSE
  OUTPUT "Age is accepted "
ENDIF
 UNTIL age >= min AND age <= max
 END
```

Comment: please post the error text under the code as it is depicted in your output programm

Comment: Please show us what you already did in Python - we can't help with python if we only see the pseudocode

Answer (score 2):

```
min = 18
max = 60
age = int(input('What is your age? '))
while not (min <= age <= max):
    print('Error - age must be between 18 and 60')
    age = int(input('What is your age? '))
print('Age is accepted')
```

I guess.

Comment: @IMCoins I guess he just wants this task to be done and asking for code he has would take a while. But I agree that we should let them understand that this is not "Do for me" website.

Comment: I don't know what's disturbing me the most in your comment. The fact that it `would take time and he just wants the job done` or the fact that you agree with me that we should make people understand this is a helping site, and not a `Do for me` code site, but still : we do it anyways.

Comment: @IMCoins it's like I've made an exception. Dunno why.

Answer (score 1):

The `REPEAT ... UNTIL <condition>` construct is something like a `do ... while`-loop in many languages. Python does not have something like this.

I can think of two solutions for this:

```
while True:
    ...
    if <condition>:
        break
```

or

```
continue_loop = True
while continue_loop:
    ...
    if <condition>:
        continue_loop = False
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do while loop with a if condition to breakout when criteria is met.

```
min = 18
max = 60


while True:
    print("what is your age?")
    INPUT age # or some other command reading from input

    if age < min or age > max:
        print(“Error - age must be between 18 and 60 ")
    else:
        print("Age is accepted ")

    if age >= min AND age <= max:
        break
```

Have put the min/max and output values outside of loop as there is no reason to re-set it each time.
You could also break out from loop in the else block where you program is happy with inserted value.

Comment: There is a syntax error in your answer. --> “

Answer (score 0):

This might be a simple example for the code you have written.

```
    min = 18
    max = 60
    print("Enter your age")
    age = int(input())
    if(age < min or age > max):
        print("Error : Age must be between 18 and 60")
    else: print("Age is accepted and you age is "+ str(age))
```

Answer (score 0):

Repeat until could be defined like that:

```
min = 0
max = 100
while true:
    age = int(input('age: '))
    if (min < age < max):
        print('age {0} accepted'.format(age))
        break;
    print('age should be between {0} and {1}'.format(min, max))
    age = int(input('age: '))
```